# Sync Github Repo to Dreamhost Site

Tags: git, deployment, github, synchronization, dreamhost

I want to host a website with [Dreamhost](http://dreamhost.com/) whose files are editable via [Github](https://github.com/) such that when commits are pushed to Github the actual website updates. How can I best achieve this? Dreamhost offers [Subversion](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Subversion) as a one-click install. For [git](http://git-scm.com/) it gives [cautionary advice](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Git). I prefer git over Subversion. [Syncing git to Subversion](http://www.google.com/search?q=sync+git+repo+to+svn+site%3Astackoverflow.com) seems viable. Where in the directory structure would Subversion need to be installed in order to have the site display the content (not the repo)? Recommendations?

Comment: do you have ssh access to your server?

Comment: @Chronial Yes SSH access is possible in Dreamhost.

Comment: then just follow the tutorial given on the site you linked. Set up a repo on the server and push to it. Make sure that git is installed, first.

Comment: @Chronial Then I guess you mean the SSH method is better than the Webdav. Basically I want to figure out the setup that's least likely to be problematic. The `post-receive` hooks looks like what I need for the actual display.

Comment: No – all you need to do is: ssh to the server, run `git init --bare .` in an empty dir and run `git clone ssh://myserver/path/to/dir` on your client. Done. (as long as git is installed on the server)

Comment: @Chronial Thanks for clarifying. I got it to work without needing to create an extra repo. See answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it to work using [simple-php-git-deploy](https://github.com/markomarkovic/simple-php-git-deploy). No extra repo needed. Github [post-receive](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks) hooks on the Github repo notify the [deploy.php](https://github.com/markomarkovic/simple-php-git-deploy/blob/master/deploy.php) file on the server to deploy the changes. There's just a few lines in `deploy.php`  to edit. [survitals.com](http://survitals.com) updates when I push to its Github repo.

- For [Dreamhost](http://dreamhost.com/) the `TARGET_DIR` defined in `deploy.php` needed to be like `/home/user/example.com/`.
- It lets you to have files on the server that are not in the repo. For security I omitted `deploy.php` itself from Github because it shows the `SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN`.
- In `deploy.php` use URI-safe characters for the `SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN` b/c it gets used as a query parameter.

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but I am trying to get this to work with my Dreamhost account. I have the deploy.php file setup and when I go to the URL it is at it seems to be working. For some reason the files aren't updating on the server when I push changes to GitHub. Any idea why? I have the web hook in place.

Comment: @Andrew If you go directly to the hook URL on your site (/deploy.php?sat=...) does it show errors?

Comment: It doesn't, that is why I am confused. Anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: was it just the cache maybe ?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. If I go directly to deploy.php myself it works, but the webhook is giving a "service timeout" issue.